# Queue individual jquery functions

Tags: jquery, function, queue

I am trying to build an Apple style messenger demo for a project. Each profile pic, typing bubble, and the actual message bubble all have their own classes.
I have used jQuery to add delays to show and hide elements to make it look as though its a proper messenger app.
The issue I have is its extremely delicate as the whole page relies on delays and if one is out of sync, it screws up the entire page.
I thought using queue and dequeue would sort this out as I expected each function to run and then be kicked out the queue, making sure everything fires at the correct time.
Ideally, I’d like each chat function to be independent of each other and only fire once the previous function has completed.

Any ideas on how to do this would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've moved the functions to be called after dequeuing the elements.

** EDIT 2 **

I've now grouped each action under the same function.

Here is my js:

```
    function chat1() {
    $('div.chat1.jonProfile,div.chat1.bubble.jonBubble,div.chat1.chat-bubble').queue(function () {
      $('div.chat1.jonProfile').show(0);
      $('div.chat1.jonProfile').dequeue();
      $('div.chat1.bubble.jonBubble').hide(0).delay(3000).show(0);
      $('div.chat1.bubble.jonBubble').dequeue();
      $('div.chat1.chat-bubble').show(0).delay(3000).hide(0);
      $('div.chat1.chat-bubble').dequeue();
      chat2();
    });
  }

  function chat2() {
    $('div.chat2.bubble.jonBubble,div.chat2.chat-bubble').queue(function () {
      $('div.chat2.bubble.jonBubble').hide(0).delay(6000).show(0); // 6 Secs
      $('div.chat2.bubble.jonBubble').dequeue();
      $('div.chat2.chat-bubble').hide(0).delay(3000).show(0).delay(3000).hide(0);
      $('div.chat2.chat-bubble').dequeue();
      chat3();
    });
  }

  function chat3() {
    $('div.chat3.julieProfile,div.chat3.chat-bubble,div.chat3.bubble.julieBubble').queue(function () {
      $('div.chat3.julieProfile').hide(0).delay(6000).show(0);
      $('div.chat3.julieProfile').dequeue();
      $('div.chat3.chat-bubble').hide(0).delay(6000).show(0).delay(3000).hide(0);
      $('div.chat3.chat-bubble').dequeue();
      $('div.chat3.bubble.julieBubble').hide(0).delay(9000).show(0);
      $('div.chat3.bubble.julieBubble').dequeue();
    });
  }
```

// HTML

```
<div id="chatWindow">
  <div class="chat1 anneProfile"></div>
  <div class="chat1 chat-bubble left">
    <div class="loading">
      <div class="dot one"></div>
      <div class="dot two"></div>
      <div class="dot three"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat1 bubble jonBubble">
    lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="chat2 chat-bubble left">
    <div class="loading">
      <div class="dot one"></div>
      <div class="dot two"></div>
      <div class="dot three"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat2 bubble jonBubble">
   lorem ipsum
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="chat3 julieProfile"></div>
  <div class="chat3 chat-bubble right">
    <div class="loading">
      <div class="dot one"></div>
      <div class="dot two"></div>
      <div class="dot three"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat3 bubble julieBubble">
    lorem ipsum
  </div>
```

//CSS

```
div#deviceScreen7 {
  //background: url("@{image-path}Screen_7.1_Normal_New.png") no-repeat !important;
  width: 640px;
  height: 1136px;
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  //left: 640px;
  left: 0;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "conversations" "footer";
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto 20px;
  grid-template-rows: 93px 935px auto;
  background: #fff;
  div#scrollBox {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20px auto 20px;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative;
    div#chatWindow {
      grid-column-start: 2;
      grid-row-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: 3;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      //height:3000px;
      div.chatbox1{
        positon: relative;
      }
      div.bubble {
        margin-top: 20px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 14px 14px 18px 14px;
        line-height: 18px;
        border: solid 1px #ededed;
        button {
          display: block;
          border-left: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
          border-right: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
          border-bottom: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
          color: #0e71b8;
          background: #fff;
          margin: 0 -15px;
          padding: 10px;
          font-size: 18px;
          font-weight: 600;
          &:first-of-type {
            margin-top: 15px;
            border-bottom: none;
          }
          &.active{
            color: #6c9ccb;
            border-top: solid 2px #f1f1f1;
          }
        }
      }
      .options {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
        padding-bottom: 0;
      }

      div.anneProfile {
        background: url("@{image-path}@{sprite-image}") -14px -2087px no-repeat;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        float: left;
        &.chat1 {
          margin-top: 20px;
        }
      }

      div.anneBubble {
        background: #0E71B8;
        color: #fff;
        position: relative;
        &.chat1 {
          margin-top: 20px;
          margin-left: 95px;
          width: 208px;
        }
        &.chat2 {
          margin-left: 95px;
          width: 338px;
        }

      div.jamesProfile {
        background: url("@{image-path}@{sprite-image}") -104px -2087px no-repeat;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        float: right;
        &.chat3 {
          margin-top: 20px;
        }
      }
      div.jamesBubble {
        background: #ededed;
        color: #555;
        &.chat3 {
          width: 306px;
          margin-right: 20px;
          float: right;
          text-align: right;
        }
        &.chat4 {
          width: 393px;
          margin-right: 20px;
          float: right;
          text-align: right;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you include a working example of your code, or at least the HTML/CSS. It's hard to visualise your issue without it. I'm also certain your code can be DRY'd up a lot

Comment: Added the rest of the code. Yeah i'm aware of how much better this code could be as i'm basically repeating myself all the way through the script. Once i get a better understanding of this i'll go ahead and refactor the code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Is it that calling the functions without any parameters is screwing it up?

Comment: Any help on this one would be appreciated.